# how to add percent calculator Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, addition, calculator

I am new to programming began to learn kotlin right away
I don’t understand how to add percent to the calculator
heap percent I created but it does not work correctly
I could not find how to add percent, they all write differently, but it doesn’t work for me
I hope for your help I apologize if there was already a topic

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        tvZero.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("0") }
        tvOne.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("1") }
        tvTwo.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("2") }
        tvThree.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("3") }
        tvFour.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("4") }
        tvFive.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("5") }
        tvSix.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("6") }
        tvSeven.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("7") }
        tvEight.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("8") }
        tvNine.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("9") }
        tvDot.setOnClickListener { setTextFields(".") }

        tvPlus.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("+") }
        tvMinus.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("-") }
        tvMul.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("*") }
        tvDivide.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("/") }
        tvOpen.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("(") }
        tvClose.setOnClickListener { setTextFields(")") }
        tvPercent.setOnClickListener { setTextFields("%") }

        tvClear.setOnClickListener {
            math_operation.text = ""
            result_text.text = ""
        }

        tvBack.setOnClickListener {
            val str = math_operation.text.toString()
            if (str.isNotEmpty()) {
            math_operation.text = str.substring(0, str.length - 1)

            }
            result_text.text = ""
        }
        tvEquals.setOnClickListener {
            try {

                val ex = ExpressionBuilder(math_operation.text.toString()).build()
                val result = ex.evaluate()

                val longRes = result.toLong()
                if (result == longRes.toDouble())
                    result_text.text = longRes.toString()
                else
                    result_text.text = result.toString()

            } catch (e:Exception) {
                Log.d("error", "message: ${e.message}")

            }
        }

    }
            fun setTextFields(str: String) {
                if (result_text.text != "") {
                    math_operation.text = result_text.text
                    result_text.text = ""
                }

                math_operation.append(str)


            }
        }
```

Comment: I actually do not understand what you want to do... Can you please clarify: Are you having troubles to add a percent character "%" to the text view?
Furthermore, it would be helpful if you could extend your code sample in such a way that it is reproducible on ones pc.

Comment: I want to add % to the calculator but don’t know how to do it  
 (https://imgur.com/a/BJPaOXK)

Comment: So if you click on the percent button, it won't be added to your "expression" text view?

Comment: % does not work after pressing%, incorrect answers come out

Comment: for example 1+10% button = does not work

Comment: So the expressionbuilder does not evaluate your input correctly? Are you sure that the expression builder is able to process percents?

Comment: everything seems to be right